# WPF end current Thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a `WPF` application that contains a `button`. When the button is clicked, I want to show a new Window, loading some `UI` stuff into the new window, then close it. I create a new `UI` thread so that my main application does not freeze. Below is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Window window = new Window();
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            window.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            window.AllowsTransparency = true;
            window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            window.Show();

            //some UI activity

            window.Close();                
            Dispatcher.Run();                
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        //some more activities
```

I expected that the thread will end after `window.Close()`, but it does not.

`//some more activities` never been called because the thread does not end.

Is there any way to end current thread without call `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using thread.Join() you will block the main thread while waiting for the one which created the `Window`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        w.Show();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                 w.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => w.myTextBox.Text = i.ToString());
                 Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        });

        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("Window is now closed");
}
```

I never tried this before but let's have a look.

`Window1` is showing up and execution skips straight to Dispatcher.Run(); which will block and keep this thread alive .

While this is happening you can do your job with your newly created window and in my example I'm just updating some strings.

I am doing all the work inside a `Task` in order to keep the UI responsive.

Oh, and here Window1's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Stack9June2018EndCurrentThread.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stack9June2018EndCurrentThread"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBox"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

In case more work is needed on Window1's instance, just add helper methods there and let them do their job. Be sure to do all the work on the Window1's Dispatcher.